# Issue when moving up down in a THorzScrollBox to scroll it's parent TVertScrollBox

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-xe, delphi-xe8

I'm facing a problem with this 2 ScrollBox, one is `TVertScrollBox` which display whole screen and it have a `THorzScrollBox`  in it, my problem is if i want to touch to the HorzScrollbox item and move up and down, my VertScrollBox have to scroll same as. Are there any ways to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

//Edit 1 : I'm using a gesture and ScrollBy(x,y) function to do with this issue. But it seem a bit laggy(not smooth) and still the HorzitonScrollBox scroll it own. A image for this(http://i.imgur.com/weOqW0R.gifv). Still watting another solution to do this

Comment: did u solve your problem ?

Comment: I'm also interested in this... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using UICollectionView as given in below example project.

http://damir.me/implementing-uicollectionview-layout

Source code link: http://bascarsija.s3.amazonaws.com/CollectionView.zip

After downloading this source code, In build settings change the value of the "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" to Default Compiler and run the app.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found a simple answer.

When you have a `THorzScrollBox` inside of a `TVertScrollBox`, set `THorzScrollBox.Touch.InteractiveGestures.Pan` to `False`.